# Цвет фона приложения при его запуске

Tags: android

При запуске приложения происходит анимация: увеличивается какое-то белое окно, а затем появляется начальное activity. Ниже прикрепил изображение (поймал с 4-го раза:)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот у меня вопрос. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить цвет этого окна? А то у меня начальное activity имеет черный фон и это всё смотрится совсем не хорошо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это скорей всего системное окно, оно зависит от выставленной темы, если у Вас черный цвет попробуйте в вашем стиле прописать так:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
```